# jsPDF Autotable custom row on every page

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using autotable for jsPDF and I want to put a row with specific text and styling on a certain row of every page and I'm not sure how to do this.  I don't want to use the header. (I am using the header for a generic header on every page.) I want my custom 'header' row to appear on the first page on row 4, but on subsequent pages, I want it on row 2 of each page.

I can count every line on the page and then add my row in, but that seems tedious. I think maybe I can use a key, but I'm not sure how. I am building an array and using that to display the entire autotable.

These are the things I have tried:

Count every row and plop my custom row where I want it. However, then I don't know how to format that row that has 5 columns, without a rowspan.  The below 'content' usage doesn't work.  I seem to be only able to use the 'content' when I use a rowspan.  But I want each column in my personalized header row to correspond with the columns below them.

```
this.tableRows.push(
  [
    {
      content: ['Armband'],['Dog'],['Breed'],['Owner'],
      styles: { halign: 'left', fillColor: [255, 255, 255], fontStyle: 'bold', lineWidth: .1, },
   }
  ]
)
```

Maybe I can use willDrawCell but I'm not sure how to do that either.  I can do it fine for row number 5, but if I want it on the fifth row of page one, then row two of subsequent pages, how would I do that?

```
willDrawCell: (data) => {
  var doc = data.doc
  var rows = data.table.body
  console.log('doc ', data)
  if (data.row.index === 5) {
    doc.setFont(undefined, 'bold')
    doc.setFillColor(192, 192, 192)
    doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0)
  } else {
    doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0)
  }
},
```

Here is my first page:
[image]

.x
.x
.
x
.
x
.

And here is page 2, where I want the custom header row to appear:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

`autoTable` has a callback for every page added while drawing that table, called `didDrawPage`.

I can suggest you to keep a `boolean` flag that becomes **`true`** when document draws a page and becomes **`false`** once the **nth** row is drawn.